# Multiple refs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a Container, that should have references to some of it's children components:

```
const Container = () => {
  const blocks: HTMLDivElement[] = [];

  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation currentBlock={currentBlock} blocks={blocks} />
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But, when I try to render `Navigation` component, the `blocks` variable is an empty array.

I tried converting `blocks` variable to a reference using `useRef` hook:

```
const Container = () => {
  const blocks = useRef<HTMLDivElement[]>([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation currentBlock={currentBlock} blocks={blocks.current} />
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.current.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.current.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.current.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.current.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`blocks` is still an empty array on render, but after that it becomes a valid array of references that I wanted.

Is there any way to update `Navigation` component without rerendering `Container`?

**EDIT**:
Here's my `Navigation` component:

```
const Navigation = ({ currentBlock, blocks }: { currentBlock: number, blocks: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement[]>}) => {
  console.log(blocks.current);
  return (
    <nav>
      {blocks.current.map((_, idx) => (
        <NavigationLink key={idx} active={currentBlock === idx} />
      ))}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

In my console, I have this output:

[image: Screenshot]

The `Navigation` component doesn't render any `NavigationLink`s, as if the array is empty.

Comment: To get the elements' refs you should render them first...

Answer (score 0):

To store the refs, you should use the `useRef` hook. However you must pass on the refs to another component, not by using blocks.current but just blocks. This way it would ensure that the props used by the navigation component can then access the mutated properties since a re-render is not triggered when the refs are assigned

```
const Container = () => {
  const blocks = useRef<HTMLDivElement[]>([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation currentBlock={currentBlock} blocks={blocks} />
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.current.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.current.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.current.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
      <div ref={(ref) => ref && blocks.current.push(ref)}>
        // ...
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now inside the Navigation component you can make use of `props.blocks.current`

Comment: The issue is still present - in my `Navigation` component the blocks.current array is still empty on initial render. I edited my question...